# FFmpeg drawbox with fill color

Tags: ffmpeg

From [doc](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawbox), I use below command to draw a box and fill it with color.

```
 ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -vf "drawbox=x=0:y=570:w=in_w:h=40:color=pink@0.5:t=fill" output_1.mp4
```

I got an error.

> [Parsed_drawbox_0 @ 0x7fa5c6f05840] [Eval @ 0x7ffee6f23bc0] Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'fill'
>       Last message repeated 5 times
>   [Parsed_drawbox_0 @ 0x7fa5c6f05840] Error when evaluating the expression 'fill'.
>   [Parsed_drawbox_0 @ 0x7fa5c6f05840] Failed to configure input pad on Parsed_drawbox_0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You seem to be using an older ffmpeg version; upgrade or use `max` in place of `fill`.

Answer (score 1):

you can set `t`(thickness) equal to `h`(height) .

Answer (score -1):

```
import ffmpeg

istream = ffmpeg.input("aaa.mp4")

istream = ffmpeg.drawbox(istream, x=0,  width='iw', height='ih/2', y='ih/2', color='red', t="max")

ostream = ffmpeg.output(istream, "bbb.mp4")

ffmpeg.run(ostream)
```